# Passing jwt token/userid from `app.post()` to the `app.get()` route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, middleware

This is my `app.post()`which gets form data from client.

```js
app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { emailid, password } = req.body
  const user = await User.findOne({ emailid }).lean()

  if (!user) {
    return res.json({ status: 'error', error: " Invalid username/Password" })
  }
  if (bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id, emailid: user.emailid }, 'secret', { expiresIn: '24h' })
    return res.json({ status: 'ok', data: token, user_id: user._id })
  }
  res.json({ status: 'error', error: " Invalid username/Password" })
})
```

I need to pass the `jwt` token or the `user_id` to my

```js
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.render('index')
})
```

Comment: The `/api/login` route will be executed only once, but the JWT will be needed by several subsequent requests, I assume. So you must send the token back to the client, which must then include it (as `Authorization: Bearer <JWT>` header) in every subsequent request. See also https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/flows/authorization-code-flow. Therefore, it is actually the client that does the "token passing".

Answer (score 1):

For this, you will need to create an authentication middleware that will check your request headers for a `jwt token`, which you can then decode to get the `user_id` or any other data that you passed to it during encryption. A sample middleware can look like the one below

```
const isAuth = (req) => {
  const authorization = req.headers["authorization"];
  if (!authorization) throw new Error("You need to log in");
  const token = authorization.split(" ")[1];
  const { user_id} = verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
  return {user_id, token};
};
```

After you setup your authorization middleware, you can then go ahead and use it in your routes like so

```
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
const {token, user_id) = isAuth(req);
    //use token and user_id here or throw error if not available in case this is a protected route
  res.render('index')
})
```

Comment: but how do i pass the jwt token in the headers?

Comment: @KaartikNayak do you have the client side ready or are you testing this using postman?

Comment: basically the client side is just a form which sends a post req to /api/login

Comment: are you using a framework or just Javascript, HTML, and CSS?

Comment: express with `ejs`

Comment: Yes, let us have a look at that as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236995/discussion-between-alex-masinde-and-kaartik-nayak).